# Initialize int variable to minus one in C#

Tags: c#

I've come across some code where the variables are initialized to minus one. That's in some old code, is there any reason behind that? Because as far as I know all value types are initialized to zero.

I've tested the code and it doesn't change anything to leave the int variable uninitialized or with minus one, the result is the same.
Would you enlighten me?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        SampleDelegate del = new SampleDelegate(SampleMethodOne);
        del += SampleMethodTwo;
        int Number = -1; //or -> int Number;
        int returnedValue = del(out Number);

        Console.WriteLine("returnedValue = {0}", returnedValue);
        Console.ReadLine(); 
    }

    public static int SampleMethodOne(out int Number)
    {
       return Number = 1;
    }
    public static int SampleMethodTwo(out int Number)
    {
        return Number = 3;
    }
 }
```

`public delegate int SampleDelegate(out int Number);`

`/returns 2`

Comment: Am I missing something? Where's the -1? Anyway, you'd probably just have to ask the person that made the code why they made that decision, odds are good there is a reason and we'd never know it. Best guess is that 0 has a meaning.

Comment: The person who wrote the code is probably the only person who can tell you for definite what their reasoning was. We can only speculate.

Comment: Well, you have mentioned the difference already yourself and this was probably the reason to use -1: it is different to the default value so you know when the value has changed to 0. I guess also that negative values are impossible but 0 is valid.

Comment: It's pretty pointless to initialize an `out` parameter variable to *any* value, because the contract for an `out` parameter guarantees that the method will set the value - the initialized value is thrown away. It also seems odd for a method to return the `out` parameter; it's like passing the value back to the caller twice. I would guess that whoever wrote this code didn't really know what they were doing, and that it's not a good example for learning how to program.

Comment: The code you posted is just to give en example of your issue or is it the actual code?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

TL;DR: it depends, maybe there is no answer

Possible answer:

1. Initializing variable is better. you never know how it can be used in some later functions where having an unexpected value may be dangerous (when the code is optimized, you cannot be sure of the default value if not initialized).
2. In some case, an int may be used for some compatibility reason in the API when you just need an uint. In such a case, initializing to a negative value may be an easy way to detect an unset/invalid value.
3. No real reason, just an habit from the developer. I agree with comments, ask him if possible

Comment: It seems like it's as you say, because I've searched a lot and the only logic reason I found is that to detect if the value of the variable have changed, anyways thank you for the answer.